# How to render the Dictionary values in the table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dictionary

I have a Dictionary containing some values into it.
I want to render this values using table
But I already have one table that is coming from other Model.This model containing the Dictionary
I want to populate the Dictionary values into the table.

```
public class UnPaidChargesByStockRequestVM {
        public int? SalvageId { get; set; }
        public string Culture_Code { get; set; }
        public List<UnPaidChargesByStockResponseVM> GetResuestModel;

    }
public class UnPaidChargesByStockResponseVM {
        public int? buyer_id { get; set; }
        public int? stockNo { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, decimal?> SalvageBuyerFees { get; set; }
  }
```

This SalvageBuyerFees having some values into it.I want to display it on view.
My View

```
 @model BuyerPaymentMockUI.Web.Models.UnPaidChargesByStockRequestVM
    <table class="table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>buyer_id</th>
                <th>stockNo </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.GetResuestModel) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.buyer_id</td>
                    <td>@item.stockNo</td>
                </tr>
                }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now i want to display the SalvageBuyerFees values as well

Comment: How many items do you have in your `SalvageBuyerFees` dictionary? Because it's possible you may have to add in another `foreach` loop.

Comment: SalvageBuyerFees having 17 items in it

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use a nested `foreach` loop:

```
@model BuyerPaymentMockUI.Web.Models.UnPaidChargesByStockRequestVM
<table class="table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>buyer_id</th>
            <th>stockNo </th>
            <th>SalvageBuyerFees key</th>
            <th>SalvageBuyerFees value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.GetResuestModel) {
            foreach (var sbf in item.SalvageBuyerFees {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.buyer_id</td>
                    <td>@item.stockNo</td>
                    <td>@sbf.Key</th>
                    <td>@sbf.Value</th>

                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But here I am getting the same row getting repeated that is not ideal

Comment: Well you didn't specify what it was that you wanted so I had to guess.